# Need to display WPF UI from Native c++ application How can we do this

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, managed-c++

I am having c++ native application and from this native application we want to display the C# WPF UI by loading it in the form of dll.
Need input whether we can achieve this or not?
Any help in this regard would be very helpful.

Comment: "loading it in the form of dll" NO. embedded? maybe. depending on how much trouble you guys are willing to go thru

Comment: We want to achieve WPF UI on demand (like some configuration settings set from UI) which will be called from C++ native application.

Comment: then you need to recompile your c++ to target .net framework. meaning that it will no longer be a native application but rather c++ code running on .net

Answer (score 0):

If your native C++ application is COM aware, you can use COM interop to export a Windows Forms control that contains an ElementHost; which in turn contains WPF components.

I've worked on VB6 applications that utilized this technique in order to use WPF UI.

Comment: Yes our native application is COM aware and was thinking of using the COM to achieve this, but I did not have any pointers or references as the starting point. Can you please provide some samples or reference link for the same. I just referred the below link https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/828736/how-to-call-a-managed-dll-from-native-visual-c-code-in-visual-studio-n but not sure how to display the UI using it.

Comment: I haven't worked with Win32 (invoking COM Interop). I would speculate that you would need to expose the control handle (Hwnd) as part of your COM interface. The link in the answer below appears to support that.